# Showing a SharePoint site inside a Windows Kiosk session

Tags: authentication, windows-authentication

I would like to display a private SharePoint site on a "public" display inside my company. We're using a solution which requires me to use a Windows Kiosk session. Can I grant the "kiosk device" specifically full read access to the site?
The "kiosk display" is often rebooted, which means creating a new user specifically for accessing the SP site on the device should be an issue, since I would have to manually login with it again every reboot.

Is there a solution to this issue?

Thank you very much